# Layer Slider in RTL direction

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am trying to make this Layer Slider work in RTL direction but it is not working. Not sure if it is possible to change it or not

http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.9.4/page_home1.html

tried change following properties breaks the design

```
.ls-slide, .ls-layer {
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.ls-slide > * {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Any help in this regard is appreciated

Even RTL theme of this page breaks
http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.9.4/RTL/page_home1.html